# Alternating between 2 images with JS instead of using a GIF

Tags: javascript

I need to alternate a load of images on the page between ones with a neon style glow and one without (only on certain parts of the image like e.g. the outline). So I've decided it would be more performant and better for site speed (mainly load time) to alternate the images with JS. The working code is as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  /*#__alternate image _1 to _2__*/
  var alternate12 = document.querySelectorAll('.alternate12');
  var alternate12mob = document.querySelectorAll('.alternate12mob');
  var mobileWidth = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');

  if (alternate12 || alternate12mob) {
    alternateFunc();
  }

  function alternateFunc() {
    if (mobileWidth.matches) {
      alternate12Mobile();
    } else {
      alternate12Desktop();
    }
  }

  function alternate12Desktop() {
    alternate12.forEach(function(linkElement, i) {
      if (linkElement.hasAttribute("srcset")) {
        var images = [linkElement.srcset, `${linkElement.srcset.slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
        var i = 0;
        //loop through the images array
        var renew = setInterval(function() {
          if (images.length == i) {
            i = 0;
          } else {
            linkElement.srcset = images[i];
            i++;
          }
        }, 400);
      } else if (linkElement.hasAttribute("src")) {
        var images = [linkElement.src, `${linkElement.src.slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
        var i = 0;
        //loop through the images array
        var renew = setInterval(function() {
          if (images.length == i) {
            i = 0;
          } else {
            linkElement.src = images[i];
            i++;
          }
        }, 400);
      }
    });
  }

  function alternate12Mobile() {
    alternate12mob.forEach(function(linkElement, i) {
      if (linkElement.hasAttribute("srcset")) {
        var images = [linkElement.srcset, `${linkElement.srcset.slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
        var i = 0;
        //loop through the images array
        var renew = setInterval(function() {
          if (images.length == i) {
            i = 0;
          } else {
            linkElement.srcset = images[i];
            i++;
          }
        }, 400);
      } else if (linkElement.hasAttribute("src")) {
        var images = [linkElement.src, `${linkElement.src.slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
        var i = 0;
        //loop through the images array
        var renew = setInterval(function() {
          if (images.length == i) {
            i = 0;
          } else {
            linkElement.src = images[i];
            i++;
          }
        }, 400);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" class="alternate12" srcset="aaa_1.jpg?$staticlink$">
  <source media="(max-width: 767px)" class="alternate12mob" srcset="aaa_mob_1.jpg?$staticlink$">
  <img class="i-image-1928 alternate12" src="aaa_1.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="">
</picture>
```

I'm trying to learn JS and the DRY principle is always so key it seems, how can I not repeat myself 4 times in those `if (src) and if (srcset)` blocks of code. In other words how can I make this code follow DRY better. I know I'm missing an easy way of doing it as there is a lot of repetition in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `linkElement.srcset` you could do a variable/attribute `attributeName='srcset'`

```
var attributeName = 'srcset'
var images = [linkElement[attributeName], `${linkElement[attributeName].slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
var i = 0;
//loop through the images array
var renew = setInterval(function() {
  if (images.length == i) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    linkElement[attributeName] = images[i];
    i++;
  }
}, 400);
```

So now the only difference in the code blocks is the value you assign to `var attributeName`.

To reuse that code you need to wrap that in a function:

```
function changeImage(attributeName, linkElement, images) {
  var images = [linkElement[attributeName], `${linkElement[attributeName].slice(0,-5)}2.jpg`];
  var i = 0;
  //loop through the images array
  var renew = setInterval(function() {
    if (images.length == i) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      linkElement[attributeName] = images[i];
      i++;
    }
  }, 400);
}
```

Now you have a generic function for both cases that you could call with `changeImage('srcset', linkElement, images)` or `changeImage('src', linkElement, images)`

So the same technique to change your `alternate12...` to `alternate12Images(alternate12)` and `alternate12Images(alternate12mob)`

Comment: ah this is exactly what i didn't get.. how to make a string variable 'srcset' into a into a javascript object.. so you do it with square bracket like this.. [attributeName]?

Comment: ah i can't get it to work, keeps saying attributeName is not defined, any chance you could edit that to show how it fits into my code above please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a spritesheet with n-number of frames and swap between them.

> [image: spritesheet]

The spritesheet above contains 16 sequential frames of 128px² sub-images.

```js
// Functional
let speed = 250, index = 0, frames = 16;
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.loader').forEach(loader => {
    loader.className = 'loader loader-' + ('00' + (index % frames)).substr(-2);
  });
  index++;
}, speed);

// Object-Oriented
class Loader {
  constructor(config) {
    this.className = config.className;
    this.frames = config.frames;
    this.index = 0
    this.speed = config.speed || 1000;
  }
  start() {
    if (this.intervalId != null) stop();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.update(), this.speed);
  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
  update() {
    let self = this, suffix = ('00' + (self.index % self.frames)).substr(-2);
    document.querySelectorAll(`.${this.className}`).forEach((el) => {
      el.className = `${this.className} ${this.className}-${suffix}`;
    });
    self.index++;
  }
}
let loader = new Loader({ className: 'loader-cls', frames: 16, speed: 1000/16 });
loader.start();
setTimeout(() => loader.stop(), 6000); // Stop after 6 seconds...
```

```css
.loader, .loader-cls {
  display: inline-block;
  background: 0 0 url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rfp4.png') no-repeat;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.loader-00, .loader-cls-00 { background-position:     0   0 }
.loader-01, .loader-cls-01 { background-position:  -128px 0 }
.loader-02, .loader-cls-02 { background-position:  -256px 0 }
.loader-03, .loader-cls-03 { background-position:  -384px 0 }
.loader-04, .loader-cls-04 { background-position:  -512px 0 }
.loader-05, .loader-cls-05 { background-position:  -640px 0 }
.loader-06, .loader-cls-06 { background-position:  -768px 0 }
.loader-07, .loader-cls-07 { background-position:  -896px 0 }
.loader-08, .loader-cls-08 { background-position: -1024px 0 }
.loader-09, .loader-cls-09 { background-position: -1152px 0 }
.loader-10, .loader-cls-10 { background-position: -1280px 0 }
.loader-11, .loader-cls-11 { background-position: -1408px 0 }
.loader-12, .loader-cls-12 { background-position: -1536px 0 }
.loader-13, .loader-cls-13 { background-position: -1664px 0 }
.loader-14, .loader-cls-14 { background-position: -1792px 0 }
.loader-15, .loader-cls-15 { background-position: -1920px 0 }
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="loader-cls"></div>
```

### Programatically build StyleSheet

You can build a stylesheet based on the spritesheet and inject it into the head of the document.

```js
class StyleSheet {
  constructor(id) {
    this.style = document.createElement('style');
    this.style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    if (id) this.style.setAttribute('id', id);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(this.style);
  }
  insert(selector, rules) {
    if (!(this.style.sheet || {}).insertRule) {
      (this.style.styleSheet || this.style.sheet).addRule(selector, this.reduceRules(rules));
    } else {
      this.style.sheet.insertRule(`${selector} { ${this.reduceRules(rules)} }`, 0);
    }
  }
  reduceRules(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map((k) => `${k}:${obj[k]}`).join(';');
  }
}

/**
 * A loading element represented by a stylesheet.
 */
class Loader {
  /**
   * @param {string} config.className  - Class name for loader elements
   * @param {int} config.frames - Number of frames in spritesheet
   * @param {number} [config.speed=1.0] - Rate of speed typically: 1 second / number of frames
   * @param {boolean} [config.generateCSS=false] - Auto-generate frame CSS
   * @param {string} config.spriteSettings.url - Spritesheet background image
   * @param {string} config.spriteSettings.layout - Layout of the sprites
   * @param {int} config.spriteSettings.cell.width - Width of a sprite
   * @param {int} config.spriteSettings.cell.height - Height of a sprite
   */
  constructor(config, spriteSettings) {
    config = config || {};
    if (config.className === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Loader.config.className undefined');
    }
    if (config.frames === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Loader.config.frames undefined');
    }
    this.className = config.className;
    this.frames = config.frames;
    this.fps = 1000 / this.frames;
    this.speed = config.speed || 1.0;
    this.index = 0;
    if (config.generateCSS === true) {
      if (spriteSettings === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Loader.spriteSettings required if Loader.config.generateCSS == true');
      }
      this.spriteSettings = spriteSettings;
      this.generateCSS();
    };
  }
  start() {
    if (this.intervalId != null) stop();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.update(), this.speed * this.fps);
  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
  update() {
    let self = this, suffix = ('00' + (self.index % self.frames)).substr(-2);
    document.querySelectorAll(`.${this.className}`).forEach((el) => {
      el.className = `${this.className} ${this.className}-${suffix}`;
    });
    self.index++;
  }
  generateCSS() {
    let style = new StyleSheet();
    // Insert in reverse-order.
    for (let i = this.frames - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let offset = -1 * (this.spriteSettings.cell.width * i), xOff = 0, yOff = 0;
      if (this.spriteSettings.layout === 'horizontal') {
        xOff = offset;
      } else if (this.spriteSettings.layout === 'vertical') {
        yOff = offset;
      }
      style.insert(`.${this.className}-${('00' + i).substr(-2)}`, {
        'background-position': `${xOff}px ${yOff}px`
      });
    }
    style.insert(`.${this.className}`, {
      'background-image': `url("${this.spriteSettings.url}")`,
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      'background-position': '0 0',
      'width': `${this.spriteSettings.cell.width}px`,
      'height': `${this.spriteSettings.cell.height}px`
    });
  }
}

let loader = new Loader({
  className: 'loader-cls',
  frames: 16,
  generateCSS: true
}, {
  url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rfp4.png',
  layout: 'horizontal',
  cell: {
    width: 128,
    height: 128
  }
});
loader.start();
setTimeout(() => loader.stop(), 60000); // Stop after 1 minute...
```

```css
.loader-cls {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-cls"></div>
```

Comment: great idea! i should have used sprite sheets! too late to turn back now though thanks for the help